# Elastic BeanStalk fails to load the url

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a docker app using docker-compose in aws Elastic Beanstalk and after deploying all the event logs look okay but I still can’t access the application using the provided url. I initially created the app with the docker code that is provided and that works well but when I deployed a newer version with my docker-compose.yml file the url refuses to connect. I guess it's something to do with port but I have not yet figured what the real issue is

Here is my current docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  talk:
    image: coralproject/talk:4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - redis
    environment:
      - TALK_MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo/talk
      - TALK_REDIS_URL=redis://redis
      - TALK_ROOT_URL=http://127.0.0.1:3000
      - TALK_PORT=3000
      - TALK_JWT_SECRET=password
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
volumes:
  mongo:
    external: false
  redis:
    external: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the ports from 80:80 to 3000:3000 and editing the security groupsto add port 3000 to the rules